# Bootstrap to have columns with same height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I have 2 columns in a page using Bootstrap but one column is larger than the other one. What I want to do is have both columns be the same height so that I can align the contents of the shorter column at the bottom.

I've read a couple approaches like `margins`, `flexbox`, and `tables`.

I tried `flexbox` and it works for bigger screen sizes but when I go to mobile sizes the columns do not get stacked like they used to before I added flexbox styling on them. The margins I haven't tried yet because it feels a little hacky for me. The tables - I don't know, I just don't like using tables for layout in general.

Here a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8skcbj5/1/) if you want to take a stab at it.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4 class="search-header bold">Deadline</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="select-deadline" class="control-label">Deadline Type</label>
          <select name="deadline" id="select-deadline" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Upcoming</option>
            <option value="" selected="selected">Sponsor</option>
            <option value="">Internal</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="input-days" class="control-label">Due Within How Many Days?</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-days" />
        </div>
        <div class="divider bold italic"><span class="divider-line">&mdash;</span> or <span class="divider-line">&mdash;</span></div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="input-date" class="control-label">Last Day to Search</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-date" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="col-md-12 action-btn-container">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-action">Clear All</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-action">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.action-btn-container {
  text-align: right;
}
```

#### UPDATE:

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8skcbj5/4/) with how I tried to solve the problem using `flexbox`.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried flexbox and it works for bigger screen sizes but when I go to mobile sizes the columns do not get stacked like they used to before I added flexbox styling on them.

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-wrap: nowrap`.

This means that, by default, the child elements ("flex items") will be forced to stay in a single line regardless of screen size.

If you want the columns to stack vertically on smaller screens, add this to the container:

```
flex-wrap: wrap
```

Comment: Here's my updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8skcbj5/3/) with `flexbox` styling. Why does the shorter column seem to not respect the 4-8 ratio in smaller screens?

Comment: Because `.flex-col { flex: 1; }` is applied to both columns. The rule tells them to distribute space evenly among themselves. When you remove it, the Bootstrap widths are restored: https://jsfiddle.net/m8skcbj5/5/

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! I just copied that from the question I read earlier. Didn't know what it does so I didn't remove it.

Comment: Hey @Michael_B, flexbox made the columns behave differently. When they stack they don't take the entire width anymore instead they just stack but keep the width that they currently have. You can compare this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8skcbj5/6/) which is the behavior I want and your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8skcbj5/5/) with the heights equal using flexbox.

Comment: Well, you're bumping up against Bootstrap styles. You need to override them. Here's an example using a media query: https://jsfiddle.net/m8skcbj5/9/